# Implicit method for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I want to numerically solve the initial value problem of ordinary differential equation for function $u=u(t)$:
$$
u'(t)=L(u).
$$
I find an second-order implicit method:
$$
 u_{n+1}=u_n+\Delta t L(u_{n+1}-\frac{\Delta t}{2}L(u_{n+1})).
$$
Here $\Delta t$ is the time step size and $u_n$ denotes the numerical solution at $n$-th time step.

It seems that this implicit method cannot be written as a form of Runge-Kutta method. Do someone know what's the name of this method? Could it be extended to higher order?

Comment: we should have $u'(t)=L(u,t)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $k_1$ by $u_{n+1}=u_n+Δt·k_1$ and $k_2=L(u_{n+1})$. Then 
$$
k_1=L(u_n+Δt·k_1-\tfrac12Δt·k_2)
\\
k_2=L(u_n+Δt·k_1)
$$
which gives you an implicit RK scheme with tableau
$$
\begin{array}{l|ll}
\tfrac12 & 1&-\tfrac12 \\
1 & 1&0\\\hline
  & 1&0
\end{array}
$$

From the given equation one may also see that it is the time reverse of the [explicit midpoint method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_method).

As an implicit 2nd order method, the implicit midpoint method is conceptually simpler and is invariant under time reversal, so the method in question has no practical relevance.